# Can I use DNS wildcards without subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system

I know that I can create a A record like `*.app.foo.com`. But can I create one like `*-app.foo.com`?

My motivation is that I already bought a wildcard SSL certificate for `*.foo.com` and I would like to not need another one for `*.app.foo.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record),

> A wildcard DNS record is specified by using a "*" as the leftmost **label** (part) of a domain name

(Emphasis added)

That means that, no, you can't (officially) wildcard a name in the manner you propose.

The thing is, wildcards are expanded by the authoritative DNS server.  With a suitably customised DNS server, you could cause records for any request for `app-*.example.com` to return records of your choosing.  There are some trickinesses around handling `ANY` queries, but it's surprisingly straightforward to do, if you really need to.

Alternately, most DNS services can have records programmatically added, so inserting a new `app-<something>` record for every new customer you sign up (for example) is rarely an undue hardship.